# Overlapping elements in a clean manner?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple text boxes which I've placed in Bootstrap RowFluid and Span12.

Float is left, which based on width, causes 4 boxes to show up on each row.

What I'd like to do is place an X at the top right of each box so that someone can click the X and delete the box.

I can't seem to figure out how to overlap in a clean way. Can someone suggest a method and I'll hack away at it?

html

```
<div class="box-list">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <a href="/box/1">First box</a>
            <a href="/box/2">Second box</a>
            <a href="/box/3">Third box</a>
            <a href="/box/4">Fourth box</a>
            <a href="/box/5">Fifth box</a>
            ...etc
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .box-list a{
     width:22%;
     height:100px;
     font-size:20px;
     line-height: 50px;
     padding:25px 0 25px 0;
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px dashed #333333;
     float:left;
     background-color:#EEE;
     margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
     color:#333;
     display:block;
 }
```

I've tried a number of things but haven't been able to get it to look right at all. I've tried putting the links in containers and setting the CSS of the container to the above CSS. Then I added new 'delete' links where the text is only an X and put `position:absolute` but it results in really odd results. I've tried creating 2 boxes one with text and one without but then the boxes can't seem to overlap each other 100%. I'm at a loss so any suggestions would help

Including a fiddle with some changes I attempted: http://jsfiddle.net/sX2BC/

Comment: the delete link with position:absolute would be the easiest way. have it right: 0; top: 0 (or 10px, etc. if you want padding). just make sure the div that you put the link in has a `position:relative;`

Comment: @kennypu For some reason the X doesn't appear at the top when I do this. It appears a couple of pixels below. Is there a reason why? When I try and make the exact same box, it shows up a few pixels (maybe 10-20) below. I can't seem to make the exact same box overlap itself.

Comment: can you make a fiddle of what you're doing?

Comment: @kennypu I've added a fiddle to my main body. Something you should know is that I wanted my entire box to highlight when I hover over it. That's why I need to make a box perfectly overlap itself. However as per the fiddle, it shows up slightly below for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you had many margins/paddings on the container and box that affected the overlap. Removing most of them will allow the box to overlap nicely with the container. Next, I removed the `float:left` on the boxes, as it is not necessary, and will remove the box from the regular flow. Lastly, to make the a tags display as a box, I changed its display to `display:inline-block`. It should be close to what you wanted :

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sX2BC/3/

Comment: Amazing. Thank you sir. Didn't realize the padding was doing anything on an empty box. Thank you again!